# Javascript: Functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm a 13 year old coder preparing for the tech interview at Hack Reactor and one of the questions that I'm having trouble with is **What gets returned out of a function if anything?** Could someone explain to me what the answer is?

Comment: It depends on the function what it returns?

Comment: depends on the function

Comment: Whatever you return with `return` or `undefined`

Comment: This is really a big questions, functions return whatever you make them to return, this should help

Comment: Is it whatever you put into the curly braces is what gets returned out of the function like if you put an alert into the curly braces when you call the function the alert will be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) from the function OR `undefined`.

```
function test(){
    return 12;
}
```

In this case you get `12` back from a function;

```
function test2(){
    console.log('testing');
}
```

In this case you get back `undefined` which is a global property that points to the [`undefined` primitive.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Or, probably more clearly:

```
var t1 = test();
var t2 = test2();
"testing"
console.log(t1);
12
console.log(typeof t1);
"number"
console.log(t2);
undefined
console.log(typeof t2);
"undefined"
```

Comment: Is it whatever you put into the curly braces is what gets returned out of the function like if you put an alert into the curly braces when you call the function the alert will be returned

Comment: No. What is returned by a function is EXPLICITLY ONLY the value given to the `return` keyword. Otherwise it is `undefined`. If you had a function that just had an `alert` in it, the function would return `undefined`